# What is the Balmer spectrum of the p-complete stable homotopy category?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, triangulated-categories, chromatic-homotopy

When doing computations with spectra, we first reduce to working at a prime p by using the arithmetic fracture theorem: (the homotopy groups of) a spectrum of finite type can be recovered from its rationalization together with its $p$-completion for all $p$ (and a bit of information about how they fit together). This method is used to further refine $p$-local homotopy theory using the chromatic filtration. In this approach, we filter the category of finite $p$-local spectra by the Morava K-theories $K(n)$, so that we have a sequence of thick subcategories $L_n\operatorname{Sp}_{(p)}$ which give rise to an Adam-Novikov spectral sequence and can be studied using geometric information about formal groups.

From a categorical point of view, the reason this works is because these subcategories are exactly the elements of the Balmer spectrum $\operatorname{Spc}(\operatorname{Sp}_{(p)})$. What I'm wondering, though, is why we use the $p$-*local* category instead of the $p$-*complete* category. It certainly works, since we can quite easily compute $p$-completions of $p$-local finite abelian groups, but it seems like it would be more natural to consider the Balmer spectrum of $\operatorname{Sp}_p^{\wedge}$. If we look at Barthel and Beaudry's description in their chapter of the *Handbook*, for instance, they construct a direct comparison map exhibiting $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ as a retract of $\operatorname{Spc}(\operatorname{Sp})$, which they use to describe the Morava K-theories at a prime $p$ as the elements of the fiber over $p$. This isn't literally true unless we work in the $p$-complete category.

So, what actually is this Balmer spectrum? Is it the same as the spectrum of the p-local category? Is it unknown? And is there any reason not to work with this category directly?

Comment: One of the problem, I guess, is that the Balmer spectrum is usually associated to *small* (symmetric monoidal) categories. This category is not rigid (in particular, the unit is not compact), so it is difficult to extract a good small subcategory to play the game. The issue is mentioned in [Balmer's survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.08963) Rem 2.18. As mentioned there, this can be solved by studying idempotent algebras instead, which is adopted in [Clausen–Scholze's lecture notes on complex geometry](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/Complex.pdf) Lecture 5.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, from the point of view of idempotent algebras, the spectrum of p-local and p-complete objects are complement, since the p-local sphere is an idempotent algebra, and you have the corresponding stable symmetric monoidal recollement.